# Current sharing controller

Tags: power-supply, power, current

We want to implement current sharing from two supplies on our PCB. There are dedicated ICs to implement this functionality, but we could only find [UCC39002](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc39002.pdf) from TI. How come no other manufacturer carry a similar IC, or maybe we simply couldn't search properly? In summary, are there any alternatives to ucc39002 from TI?

Related link: http://focus.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/slua550/slua550.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most power supplies I've worked on inherently share by using a discrete internal solution with a few opamps and discrete components, and a load share bus connected between the power supplies in the system.

Your situation appears to be one in which two power supplies that don't already have some form of sharing need to be forced to share.

This IC is implementing forced sharing on the system side, creating a load share bus similar to what I described above.

You may want to ask your supplier if they can implement droop. There already may be a provision for it on the board that simply has to be populated. Droop doesn't require a load share bus - the regulation slightly degrades as the current goes higher, which equalizes the power supply voltages and gives you sharing.

Answer (score 2):

The first strategy should be to not have to share current between two voltage sources.  There are some ways, but it's even better to avoid this in the first place.

Why do you think you need current sharing?  Do you need too much current for one supply?  Why not get a bigger supply?  If you're trying to use switcher chips and create your own supply around them, there should be ways to beef that up.  Perhaps you need a multi-phase switcher.  That's basically multiple switching power supplies with a common controller and evenly distributed phase relationship.

Step back and explain the problem you are trying to solve instead of asking about a single solution.

Comment: There is an existing electromechanical system (a cabinet containing a number of electronics subsystems and some mechanical parts (think robot arm, etc)). We're designing another subsystem, a motor controller. The problem is that existing power sources inside this cabinet are capable of delivering 0.65X of the current that we need. There are many of them, but individually, a single one is not capable of driving our unit. Ex: 48V, 10Amps, but our "controller" needs 20Amps. We don't have the flexibility of "getting bigger supplies"

Comment: What you need goes a bit beyond sharing, actually. You need to ensure that your supplies have a brick-wall, or constant-current startup characteristic, to allow time for all of the supplies to come up without going into overload protection or latching off. Once they're up , they of course need to share to avoid having imbalance.

Comment: @SomethingBetter: If these multiple supplies weren't designed for current sharing up front, it's pretty much not going to happen.  This is not something you retrofit after the fact.  Without redoing the whole power system or adding intermediate active power handling, the best you can do is tweak the supplies to have the same regulation voltage as close as possible, then add a little resistance from each to your load.  At 20A you can't afford to drop much voltage though.